# Recreate hardware RAID 1 out of fully-mirrored disks without data loss in software RAID 1

Tags: raspberry-pi, software-raid, raid-1, ubuntu-20.04, data-loss-prevention

I have two identical hard disk drives with identical data. They were a former hardware RAID 1 on a [MSI H97M-E35](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/H97M-E35.html) mainboard with an Intel H81 Express chipset and were used as data drives (not as system drives).

Now I have connected both to my Raspberry Pi4 running an Ubuntu server 20.04. The system drive is an SD card, the two hard disk drives are contracted as `/dev/sdh1` and `/dev/sdi1`

Data is similar on both devices (mounted as read only to check).
How can I move them back into a software RAID 1 as they are still 100% in sync?

And best case without loosing all the data.
But of course I have made data backups before, just in case.

`fdisk -l` shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdi: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: 003 HN-M201RAD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x19b34eae

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdi1        2048 3907018751 3907016704  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdh: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: 003 HN-M201RAD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6dd61e30

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdh1        2048 3907018751 3907016704  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Please edit your question: What was the hardware RAID device these drives were pulled from? To the best of my knowledge, there is no real standard between RAID schemes from hardware to software. Meaning while you have two drives that are mirrored and contain the same data from hardwire RAID 1 setup, I am not too sure you can magically just recreate the same RAID 1 setup via software RAID. Perhaps someone else can advise better.

Comment: Yeah sure, good idea. Added information "on a MSI H97M-E35 mainboard with an Intel h81 express chipset."
Truth be told I would also be glad if I could just format sdi1 blank and then upon creating a new Raid 1 between sdh1 and sdi1 just get all data copied. Might take a night or two but so what :-)

Comment: Back up your data before doing anything. If all else fails create new raid 1, then copy data to it.

Comment: @NetDevil Thanks for the info! The RAID 1 array you had previously was a system disk or just data? Meaning whatever system you have now already has some system drive and the RAID setup is purely for data/storage needs. Also, I see your tags are Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu 20.04. Is this all running on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @Moab: sure did :-) doing regular backups of the data anyways as RAID 1 is no backup method but only an enhanced data loss prevention.

Comment: @Giacomo: I did not want to bloat the initial post too much but added all the information. It was and will be a data drive raid only. And yes, all running on a Raspberry Pi4